# group_by string elements in array based on their content

Tags: ruby

I want to group_by string elements of an array based on the content.

`["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"].group_by { |x| some code }`

So I want it to return:

`[["abc", "abc", "abc"],["def"],["ghi", "ghi"]]`

I've  tried the following:

`irb(main):065:0> ["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"].group_by { |x| x }`

It returns: `{"abc"=>["abc", "abc"], "def"=>["def"], "ghi"=>["ghi", "ghi"]}`

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Based on their content, in which way? What does `0`, `1`, `2` represent?

Comment: the 0, 1, 2 are the hash keys

Comment: Of course they are. What do they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want an array. Then you write:

```
["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"].group_by { |x| x }.values
```

Comment: Accepted for the simplicity

Comment: @PNY: that's confusing, you select an answer (which is a reasonable answer) that does not return what you ask for. Update the question then.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Array
  def group
    h_result = {}
    self.uniq.each_with_index {|value, i| h_result[i] = self.select{|x| x==value}}
    group = h_result
  end
end

a_test = ["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"]
h_test = a_test.group

puts h_test.inspect
```

Comment: +1 but Lukaz answer is much easier to read even through it doesn't return a hash, it would still do the job.

Comment: Yeah, his answer is definitely much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"]
Hash[a.uniq.map.with_index{|e,i| [i,[e]*a.count(e)]}]
# => {0=>["abc", "abc"], 1=>["def"], 2=>["ghi", "ghi"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a silly one-liner that would get you what you want.  Still seems kinda goofy to do, though.

```
a = ["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"]
Hash[a.group_by { |x| x }.values.map.with_index { |x, i| [i, x] }]
# => {0=>["abc", "abc"], 1=>["def"], 2=>["ghi", "ghi"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very simple, but it'll do what you wanted:

```
["abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"].group_by{|x|x}.each_with_index.inject({}){|m,a|m[a[1]]=a[0];m}
```